# CLI wallet where I can pass in a Private Key and send out ETH and then delete this key?

Tags: ether, wallets, private-key, command-line, sendtransaction

Is there a CLI command where I can pass in an ethereum private key and send some coins to another address? I'm trying to build out a reoccurring payment system where a user can send 1 eth to another address every week. But I'm looking for a wallet via the command line that can pass in a private key to do the send out. What are the best options?

Answer (score 1):

You can `npm install web3@1.2.1`, and then try this NodeJS script:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const NODE_ADDRESS = process.argv[2];
const DEST_ADDRESS = process.argv[3];
const WEI_AMOUNT   = process.argv[4];
const PRIVATE_KEY  = process.argv[5];

async function scan() {
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        process.stdout.write(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        const userGasPrice = await scan();
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        process.stdout.write("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        const hash = await scan();
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, to, value, privateKey) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                to      : to,
                value   : value,
                gas     : 21000,
                gasPrice: await getGasPrice(web3)
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function run() {
    const web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
    await send(web3, DEST_ADDRESS, WEI_AMOUNT, PRIVATE_KEY);
    if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
        web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: what is an example setting for: process.argv ? where can i find a node address? and what do i put for wei amount? i'm guessing dest_address is where the coins are going and private key is the eth private key? thanks!!!

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ: **Node Address** (1st input) example: `https://mainnet.infura.io`. **Dest Address** (2nd input): The account that you want to transfer to. **Wei Amount** (3rd input): How much wei you want to transfer. **Private Key** (4th input): The private key of the account that you want to transfer from.